# Useless resources in APK file

Tags: android, apk, android-support-library, android-resources

I've got problem with very simple application. **APK** size is now ***3 MB***, but it contains a lot of useless for me files (I think that source of this files is *Support Library*). In my application I don't use any images, but all drawable directories contains a lot of icons, buttons, etc. Is it possible to delete this images by any rule in *gradle* or other method? I use Android Studio.

Already I added to build.gradle information about languages to include in APK. I had in Hello World 80 languages before it.

Screen of files:

[image]

Comment: `I don't use any images` but the library does. However, to trim down the byte count, you could just leave the `xxxhdpi` versions, if all the images exist in such a density. You need the higher density ones, because by scaling **down** you'll get less artifacts due to pixellation.

Comment: use proguard for this problem

Comment: My team actually tried doing what @DerGol...lum suggested and it does not impact the APK size significantly (less than 1 MB for hundreds of images). Since having the images at the different densities is what Google recommends, we left all the images in the app.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post by Cyril Mottier on putting your apk on a diet. http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/ That might help.

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle build system for Android supports "`resource shrinking`": the automatic removal of resources that are unused, at build time, in the packaged app. In addition to removing resources in your project that are not actually needed at runtime, this also removes resources from libraries you are depending on if they are not actually needed by your application.

To enable this add the line `shrinkResources true` in your gradle file.

```
    android {
        ...

        buildTypes {
            release {
                shrinkResources true
            }
   }
}
```

Check the official documentation here,

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking

Comment: Thansk, It's better but a lot of useless files still exists